# How to create a matrix of 'Point2f' objects in Open CV(2.4.1)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to make a matrix of Point2f objects in Open Cv (2.4.1) using the c++ vector class.
This is the code i have:

```
vector<vector<Point> > trainingDescriptorMatrix;
    vector<Point> trainingDescriptor;



    //Search for white pixels from left to right,top to bottom. 
    for (i = 0 ; i < angle_binary.rows; i++){
        for (j = 0 ; j < angle_binary.cols; j++){

            if(angle_binary.at<bool>(i,j) != 0){ //White pixel found!!
                Point2f a(i,j);
                trainingDescriptor.push_back(a);
            }
        }

    trainingDescriptorMatrix.push_back(trainingDescriptor);
    trainingDescriptor.clear();
    }

    cout<<"trainingDescriptorMatrix size= "<<trainingDescriptorMatrix.size()<<endl;
    trainingDescriptor = trainingDescriptorMatrix[0];
    cout<<"trainingDescriptor size= "<<trainingDescriptor.size()<<endl;
```

The line of code:

```
cout<<"trainingDescriptor size= "<<trainingDescriptor.size()<<endl;
```

outputs:  trainingDescriptor size= 0

It looks like the line:

```
trainingDescriptorMatrix.push_back(trainingDescriptor);
```

makes a soft copy and then when I erase trainingDescriptor, the data is gone.

**What is the easiest way to make a matrix of 'Point2f' objects in Open CV(2.4.1) ?**

Comment: You push to `trainingDescriptorMatrix` only non-black pixels and then check the size of first row. Are you sure that your image has white pixels in the first row?

Comment: I doesn't need to have white pixels in the first row. I just searching for the position of the white pixels in the binary image.